# Why is every bounded local martingale a true martingale?

Tags: martingales, local-martingales

A cadlag process is a local martingale $\iff$ there exists a sequence of stopping times $\tau_n\to\infty (n\to\infty)$ a.s. and the stopped process $M^{\tau_n}$ is a true martingale for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Why is every bounded local martingale a true martingale?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Why do you think this is true?

Comment: Essentially the only thing stopping a local martingale from being a true martingale is integrability. Indeed, the sequence of stopping times $\tau_n = \inf \{|M_t|\geq n\}$ localizes $M$.

Comment: @Andrew Why does especially this sequnece localize $M$?